# reboot command doesn't reboot in Puppy Linux

Tags: reboot, puppy-linux

When I type the `reboot` command in a console the screen goes dark, but keeps being turned on indefinitely. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Puppy Linux has its own commands for power off and reboot; they are shell scripts that handle some of the cleanup Puppy requires. Use `wmrestart` to reboot and `wmpoweroff` to shut down. (I think they are actually borrowed from the Window Maker window manager, hence the names.)

The commands on the panel menu, at least for JWM, call these same scripts; so if you can shut down from the menu they should work in a console. They will work even if X is not running.

Comment: FYI, I use Slacko, but I'm guessing the Ubuntu-based Puppy versions function the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
reboot --force
```